# PyQt5 Virtual Keyboard on Linux Framebuffer

Tags: python, pyqt5

Trying to figure out how to get some sort of on screen keyboard solution working on my Raspberry Pi + DSI touchscreen. I saw a bunch of good examples but they are all on windows using the built in on screen keyboard. I'm trying to get mine to work in the framebuffer with LinuxFB.

My idea is when needed (such as tapping a QTextBox) a on screen keyboard will appear and type in the textbox until I tap off of it. At this point I'm considering making my own, but I feel like that will take a lot of effort and work to get working the way I want. I'm completely at a loss here of what to do so anything will help.

Thanks.

Comment: No. As I said I am not looking for Windows ones.

Comment: @OdorousWo1f The basic concept is the same: use the  [QtVirtualKeyboard](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtvirtualkeyboard-index.html) module.

Comment: It looks like qtvirtualkeyboard requires a desktop environment, which I don't have. I'm running this in the framebuffer in Linux.

Comment: I don't see any reliable source highlighting that requirement. On the contrary, it seems that it's perfectly doable even in embedded Linux devices, which certainly don't use standard desktop features. There's even a option to explicitly disable the [desktop integration](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtvirtualkeyboard-build.html#advanced-configuration-options).